# Problema com MessageBoxTimeout em VB6

Tags: visual-basic-6

Estou chamando a função MessageBoxTimeout de user32.dll mas quando uso o tipo (iType = vbInformation) sempre retorna vbOK, ou seja, não dá para saber quando ocorreu timeout.

Segue o código:

```
Public Function MsgBoxDelay(strMsg As String, strTitle As String, iTimeout As Long, iType As Integer) As Integer
    On Error GoTo trataerro
    
    MsgBoxDelay = MessageBoxTimeout(FrmCartao.hwnd, strMsg, strTitle, iType, 0, iTimeout * 1000)

    If MsgBoxDelay <> vbYes And MsgBoxDelay <> vbNo And MsgBoxDelay <> vbOK Then
        Call GravaLog("MsgBoxDelay: Erro de Timeout")
        gbAATimedOut = True
    End If

    Exit Function

trataerro:
    MsgBox "Erro VB - Função MsgBoxDelay: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
         & "Numero: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf _
         & "Descrição: " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Erro!"
End Function
```

Alguém já teve esse problema?